# mysqlclient for django in windows

Tags: mysql, django, database, web-applications

I hope you are doing great !

I am trying to do application with django framework that bringing the data from mysql database and do reports on it.

I have a problems while installing mysqlclient in windows by commands I tried a lot but always the same error

can you advice me guys ?

by the way this is the error guys.

```
C:\Users\lenovo ideapad\Desktop\django-chartit\django-project\my_chartit>pip
install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lenovo ideapad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ntl230oc\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ntl230oc\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5fst2b2v\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\lenovo ideapad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include\mysqlclient'
         cwd: C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ntl230oc\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" "-Ic:\users\lenovo ideapad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include" "-Ic:\users\lenovo ideapad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier includeÿ: 'mysql.h'ÿ: No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\lenovo ideapad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ntl230oc\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ntl230oc\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5fst2b2v\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\lenovo ideapad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

lot of people have problems to install *mysqlclient* in windows with pip, and it seems there is no solution for this.
but if you use *anaconda* you can install *mysqlclient* properly.
create virtual environment with conda and install mysqlclient with *pip install mysqlclient* command

Comment: already tried it and worked but when I try to run my application it gives me an error that mysqlclient is not there

Comment: you tried anaconda? did you activate your environment? see what packages are installed with **conda list** command